# Reorganising a framework in Xcode

Tags: xcode4

When I add a framework in Xcode 4.5, I add it via Link Binary with Libraries (in Build Phases).

However, this adds the framework at the top of my Project Navigator list in Xcode. When I then move them to the Frameworks folder the original frameworks in the "Link Binary with Libraries" section go red. E.g.

[image]

Any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Right clicking on the framework (in the Link Binary section) and selecting Show in Finder went straight to the files.

The problem was fixed by restarting Xcode.